# Evaluating trigonometric limits $\frac{2x-\sin(3x)}{4x-\sin(5x)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to evaluate this limit:

$$
\lim_{x \to 0 }\frac{2x-\sin(3x)}{4x-\sin(5x)}
$$

I did:  $$\frac{2x}{4x-\sin(5x)}-\frac{\sin(3x)3x}{(4x-\sin(5x))3x}$$

$$
\frac{2x}{4x-\sin(5x)}-\frac{3x}{4x-\sin(5x)}
$$

$$
\frac{-x}{4x-\sin(5x)}
$$

$$
\frac{-5x}{\sin(5x)(\frac{4x}{\sin(5x)}-1)*5}
$$

$$
\frac{-1}{(\frac{4x}{\sin(5x)}-1)5} =\frac{1}{5}
$$

I know that I did wrong since the answer is 1..
What did I do wrong? How can you evaluate this limit?

Thanks! :)

Comment: You forgot to multiply $4x$ by $3x$.

Comment: Are you allowed using L'hopital?

Comment: No, I'm not...,
@MathGod, can you please point in which line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easier to write it as $\frac{2x(1-\frac{\sin 3x}{2x})}{4x(1-\frac{\sin 5x}{4x})}$, then   do a bit of algebra with the $\frac{\sin x}{x}$ limit and get the result.

Comment: Why you and I got different results? where was I wrong?

Comment: I don't know; you have too many algebraic manipulations, which usually leads to a higher chance of making some mistake

Answer (score 0):

You did:

> $$\frac{2x}{4x-\sin(5x)}-\frac{\sin(3x)3x}{(4x-\sin(5x))3x}\\
> \frac{2x}{4x-\sin(5x)}-\frac{3x}{4x-\sin(5x)}\\
> \frac{-x}{4x-\sin(5x)}\\
> \frac{-5x}{\sin(5x)(\frac{4x}{\sin(5x)}-1)*5}\\
> \frac{-1}{\color{red}{(\frac{4x}{\sin(5x)}}-1)5} =\frac{1}{5}\\$$

But:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{4x}{\sin(5x)}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{5x}{\sin 5x}\frac{4x}{5x}=\frac45$$

So the limit is:
$$\frac{-1}{5(4/5-1)}=\frac{-1}{5(-1/5)}=1$$

Comment: @user1326293 edited